# Done Numerous research but unable to get the expected output

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have tried running below code in python IDE interpreter as well as in PyCharm installing the module but still getting an error,( I have installed selenium module),

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
type(browser)
browser.get('http://inventwithpython.com')
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 2, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 164, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 81, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

Comment: what is your operating system?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First look at [this](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) and install webdriver for your system.
Then add it to your system path (i don't know what is your OS so you have to find the tutorial of this by your self and it's not hard) or for temporary usage add this to your code:

```
browser=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe") 
    # Change Chrome to your desired browser and if you are not on Windows it doesn't have .exe
```